# Complete a cell at a specific positions inner HTML JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Hello using my code I get the following rendering.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccHBD.png)

```
let names = ["X", "Y"]
let ages = [22, 10]

const newTable = document.createElement("table");
newTable.innerHTML = "<thead><th>Name</th><th>Index</th><th>Age</th></thead>";
let index = []
for (let j =0 ; j< names.length; j++)
index.push(j+1)

if (names.length == ages.length) {
  for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    
    let newRow = document.createElement("tr");
    //name
    const tdName = document.createElement("td");
    tdName.textContent = names[i];
    newRow.appendChild(tdName);
    
    // index 
    let tdIndex= document.createElement("td");
    tdIndex.textContent = index[i];
    newRow.appendChild(tdIndex);

    //age
    const tdAge = document.createElement("td");
    tdAge.textContent = String(ages[i]);
    newRow.appendChild(tdAge);
    newTable.appendChild(newRow);
  }
}
const target = document.getElementById('target');
target.appendChild(newTable);
```

However I would like to display under the age cells the sums of age like this : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3toa.png)

I manage to add a newline but I don't know how to place the result in a specific cell.

```
let tdSum= document.createElement("td") 
tdSum.textContent = "Sum age" 
let newRow2 = document.createElement("tr"); 
newRow2.appendChild(tdSum) 
newTable.appendChild(newRow2)
```

**MAJ**
HTML PART:

```
<div id="target"></div>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `target.appendChild(newTable);` this is giving me an error, there is no element with an id `target` I'm going to assume is just a div you forgot to add to the question

Comment: exactly, i did maj of my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you should do is initialize a total variable and sum the values inside the loop.
Add the corresponding `td` to your total row and add the value there

```js
let names = ["X", "Y"];
let ages = [22, 10];

const newTable = document.createElement("table");
newTable.classList.add("custom-table"); 

newTable.innerHTML = "<thead><th>Name</th><th>Index</th><th>Age</th></thead>";

let index = [];
for (let j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
  index.push(j + 1);
}

let ageTotal = 0; 

if (names.length == ages.length) {
  for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    let newRow = document.createElement("tr");

    const tdName = document.createElement("td");
    tdName.textContent = names[i];
    newRow.appendChild(tdName);

    let tdIndex = document.createElement("td");
    tdIndex.textContent = index[i];
    newRow.appendChild(tdIndex);

    const tdAge = document.createElement("td");
    tdAge.textContent = String(ages[i]);
    ageTotal += ages[i]; 
    newRow.appendChild(tdAge);

    newTable.appendChild(newRow);
  }
}

const target = document.getElementById('target');
target.appendChild(newTable);

let tdSumText = document.createElement("td");
tdSumText.textContent = "Sum age:";
let newRow2 = document.createElement("tr");
newRow2.appendChild(tdSumText);

newRow2.appendChild(document.createElement("td"));

let tdSumAge = document.createElement("td");
tdSumAge.textContent = ageTotal;
newRow2.appendChild(tdSumAge);
newTable.appendChild(newRow2);
```

```css
.custom-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.custom-table th,
.custom-table td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

.custom-table th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.custom-table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: good, please accept answer and vote up if that helped you